# Equivalent of RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString in Java

Tags: java, rsa, private-key, sign

I have my private key in XML format and I am going to sign my data with that key. In .Net you can load your private key in XML format like this

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oQRshGhLf2Fh...");
```

Is there a similar method in Java? If not, what alternatives would I have?

Right now my code looks like this

```
Signature rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");  
rsa.initSign(getPrivate(“<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oQRshGhLf2Fh...”));
rsa.update(message.getBytes());
byte[] signed = rsa.sign();
```

Comment: Hi Hamed,i think we both have the same problem during implementing bank gateway for generating digital sign,have you solve this problem,if you had plz tell me beacause i really need help right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have specific support for XML crypto keys (except possibly within XMLDSIG?) but it does have pretty extensive support for XML in general. I don't do dotnet, and you don't provide test data, so I had to make some up, but I *think* the following will work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

String s = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>iDedXXkixunqnh278qUll8sWYIqyy/FfTd59kq6HDwXDapOXmYKkcsy+HTFbbLRb/bbJsMVEessdbwEVysedzx38QnWOBmGmY1VTKO8Ph3X1dkVktMT8zCbgKMBBT17dTbBE+B9zO6jqcN120qaHc8rOGC2KztM5xnEa3hNvSwk="
        +"</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB"
        +"</Exponent><P>1TmBWEl5DARzhcmaaLJELymx0Sw3xcdEqEi/2nnIYrLE1YCb0OQVHvyFBBnXEgk81zxoqkPmItNO1yHzX7UIzw=="
        +"</P><Q>o4tFYK9HE4UhaLUGzx9WpFlX8NXsXcYxzV2ewCR1EXaMCA8xowSyyDfzhUugfKI02rTeQRucTnuttbJEQsu0pw=="
        +"</Q><DP>IKzGSHxB43iPJ3JkiiS/VCbki/Rlu5Y0zEERvW4qKg3RIhKqThGVtwDldWJsVeQ6gZVNSMJM8wtEqq0WOZVpew=="
        +"</DP><DQ>UAn3GExwEqOTKDWAcZm6w5BeM6Xemj5HXWS2Lv8otDU6by9QcaH5BXgsnE3Y62ZPS8I9C8xBgT+SUlw+gBpF/Q=="
        +"</DQ><InverseQ>lbcDsYsWBNg365eRqp8n8sGLR5gdG+SV5YUAZY+Bf1P2V9cpIm8YpVcUKZXkE5SwGub7p+mCQkAbaoT/pQyXOg=="
        +"</InverseQ><D>fi82wa5DfwyV4J8eymod5v2k3w3dD3urk5D1tnmid1IZcpMCrpwNBqOPwa9FR+/T/7XiJLS4+R9LRtc0fsJn9maEfUV26ry3vqQXYRlobdsWMFuNZPmHD1S7ef1fkGthDGWMmdiKyyy5Cy+lXEM/9VlexSKMxZc3Tor+v5SCB/k="
        +"</D></RSAKeyValue>";

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
// there are many options possible for XML but not needed here
Element el = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream (s.getBytes())).getDocumentElement();
// or other source including file if applicable
String[] names = {"Modulus", "Exponent", "D", "P", "Q", "DP", "DQ", "InverseQ"};
BigInteger[] vals = new BigInteger [names.length];
for( int i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ){ 
    String v = el.getElementsByTagName(names[i]).item(0).getTextContent();
    vals[i] = new BigInteger(1, DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(v));
}
PrivateKey pk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(
        new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec (vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5], vals[6], vals[7]) );
//
Signature si = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
si.initSign(pk); si.update("foobar\r\n".getBytes()); byte[] ss = si.sign();
```

Comment: have anyone tested this?